# How to save this succulent from drying up?

Tags: watering, succulents, dryness

I have a succulent plant (not sure the exact plant name) placed indoor next to my window. It has been in this state below for the past few months.

The leaves have all dried up, including the flowers. I have been watering the flower weekly (if I recall correctly)

Flower has dried up
[image: flower has dried up]

[[image][image][image]

There is a small leaves trying to grow but it stops there for ages.
[image: small plant growth]

1. What happened to this plant? Is it still alive?
2. Should I remove the hardened dead leaves?
3. Should I increase the watering?
4. Should I change the plant soil?
5. Is there anything I can do to save the plant?
6. How to make the small plant grow faster?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is that your plant is a quite old senior citizen and probably should be replaced by a younger one. It has done its job to entertain you for years and should be allowed to retire. It has flowered, produced long stems that mostly no longer have leaves, and it requires a lot of work to move moisture and nutrients from roots up to the growing point. There is a possibility it could make a last gasp effort if cut back almost to ground level to allow that shoot at the bottom to be the only living part above ground, but it is relying on a very old root and will not do as well as a new plant.

If your plant has sentimental associations for you then by all means follow one of the many online videos to make new plants from the leaves, which can produce roots readily when given the right encouragement.